# making a simple quiz system with direct answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are a lot of free/paid quiz systems out there, but none are customizable enough, especially that I need it in RTL direction.

Anyway, I have made this simple script: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6dex/)

```
<!-- question 1 -->
<div id="01">hello there
<br />
<input id="01_correct_btn" type="button" onclick="getElementById('01_correct').style.display = 'block';
getElementById('01_continue').style.display = 'block';  this.style.display = 'none'; getElementById('01_wrong_a').style.display='none';getElementById('01_wrong_b').style.display='none'" />Hi
<br />
<input id="01_wrong_a" type="button" onclick="getElementById('01_wrong').style.display = 'block';
getElementById('01_continue').style.display = 'block';  this.style.display = 'none'; getElementById('01_correct_btn').style.display='none';
getElementById('01_wrong_b').style.display='none'" />bye
<br />
<input id="01_wrong_b" type="button" onclick="getElementById('01_wrong').style.display = 'block';
getElementById('01_continue').style.display = 'block';  this.style.display = 'none'; getElementById('01_correct_btn').style.display='none';
getElementById('01_wrong_a').style.display='none'" />thanks
<br />____________________
<div id="01_correct" style="display:none">yep, you're right...
    <br />
</div>
<div id="01_wrong" style="display:none">You are so wrong
    <br />
</div>
<input style="display:none" type="button" id="01_continue" onclick="getElementById('01').style.display = 'none';
getElementById('02').style.display = 'block'" value="continue" />
</div>
<!-- question 2 -->
<div id="02" style="display:none">question 2: Welcome to the real world</div>
```

1: How can I hide all wrong answers without having to add all their ids (`getElementByClassName` didn't work)

2: Instead of re-copying the script for each question, can this be done by JavaScript where in each new form:

a. a `"correct_btn"` displays a `"correct_note"` and hides all other buttons

b. `"wrong_btn"`s display a `"wrong_note"` and hides all other buttons

c. both `"correct_btn"` and `"wrong_btn"`s will display the continue button

d. `"continue"` button hides current div/form and displays next one

It would be much easier this way to create as much questions as possible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of `getElementByClassName` you should have used `getElementsByClassName`. `...Elements...` is plural.

Comment: thank you @JonathanM , I actually used ElementS, the typo is in this question only, sorry =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the HTML class system. As you can assign one class to multiple items. Then just create a script instead of calling the `onclick` javascript event.

I know you requested javascript, but you tagged JQuery and as I feel a JQuery script would serve you better for what you are trying to do I suggested that. Doing this with Javascript could get very wordy and complicated.

## HTML

```
<div id="Q1">Hello There<br/>
    <div class = "Q1 correct choice"><input type="button"/>Hi</div>
    <div class = "Q1 wrong choice"><input type="button"/>Bye</div>
    <div class = "Q1 wrong choice"><input type="button"/>Thanks</div>
</div>
<div id="Q1_Correct" style="display: none;">You are correct</div>
<div id="Q1_Wrong" style="display: none;">You are wrong</div>
```

You can also set up a generic correct/wrong message to be displayed.

Now, using JQuery would probably be easiest... like in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p5YY4/1/ (its not perfect, but some styling should solve some click issues... but I think you can get the gist)

## JQuery

```
$('.choice').on('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if($(this).hasClass('correct')){
        $('.choice').hide();
        var response = "#" + parent + "_Correct";
        $(response).show();
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('wrong')){
        $('.choice').hide();
        var response = "#" + parent + "_Wrong";
        $(response).show();
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

For making the script native to one document here is what you would need to set up to get it to work :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        //The script I have already provided should go here
   });
</script>
```

You can also create a separate document and call it lets say `quizWorker.js`
and then using the same layout as I just stated (in the `js` file I would also put the script in the `$(document).ready` function)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quizWorker.js"></script>
```

Comment: for some reason, it's not working here's the script in head tag

`<script src="http://http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js">
$('.choice').on('click', function() {
       var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
       if($(this).hasClass('correct')){
          $('.choice').hide();
          var response = "#" + parent + "_Correct";
          $(response).show();
       }
       if($(this).hasClass('wrong')){
          $('.choice').hide();
          var response = "#" + parent + "_Wrong";
          $(response).show();
       }
    });
</script>`

did I do it right?

Comment: Just as a note... names, classes, and id's shouldn't begin with a number.

Comment: @GaryHayes that is actually the first thing I thought, because I know that it causes errors with HTML, but this wasn't giving me errors so I took the lazy approach. I'll fix it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! (btw, edit the duplicated http in your post ^_^ my bad, sorry)....


ok, one thing remains:


I want to add a counter. Whenever correct/wrong choice is clicked, "next" button appears which does the following: 1. hides div = counter 2. counter=counter+1 3. displays div=counter (new counter value) 4. hides itself

....If a "previous" button can be added (counter=counter-1) that would be awesome!

Comment: @iJassar No worries about the typos I made them too :P! if this is the correct please consider marking it as such. If you are having issues with a counter consider asking a question about it. But for now there are a lot of ways to do that here is a good article that shows how a simple counter is made : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/making-a-number-counter

Comment: Thank you, I've just found a bug in the script....... I created 3 divs, 01, 02, 03.... changing numbers inside each div accordingly. When I answer the first question, choices are hidden in all 3 divs. help please

Comment: still no answer. Is my last comment clear?
thank you

Comment: ok, finally it worked (my first jquery edit btw ^_^)....
`if($(this).hasClass('correct')){
    var chosen = "." + parent;
    $(chosen).hide();
   // $('.choice').hide();
          var response = "#" + parent + "_Correct";
          $(response).show();
       }
       if($(this).hasClass('wrong')){
         // $('.choice').hide();
    var chosen = "." + parent;
    $(chosen).hide();
          var response = "#" + parent + "_Wrong";
          $(response).show();
       }`

Comment: @iJassar Hey sorry, went home from work. Nice! You have a working fiddle I can look at? A lot of times you need to just step away from the code for a bit

Comment: @iJassar also, any reason you unmarked the correct answer?

Comment: I did that before figuring out the answer since the question got re-unanswered =)........ for a reason, it's not working on fiddle, but it did work on [mysite](http://tibbiyat.com/248)... here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx4Dn/)

Comment: @iJassar your fiddle isn't working because you haven't imported the jQuery library :) http://jsfiddle.net/nx4Dn/2/ (You do this by in the left column where it says framework extensions you need to select jquery from the dropdown menu)

Comment: hehe, my bad, still a beginner =)
thanks a lot @metsales

Comment: @iJassar did the same thing my first time around :P